# I would like to password protect my .txt file

Tags: file, text, passwords

I would like to password protect my .txt file that has account names and passwords for my program. I know how to encrypt, but I want it to ask every time for a password. By the way, I am using windows. I preferably would not like to download a program however if it is the only option that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

https://www.axcrypt.net/

Think that should do the trick.

If you don't mind using Python https://cryptography.io/ is also an option.

Comment: **Thanks a lot!**

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer just a simple thing that lets you password protect something

Comment: https://www.axcrypt.net/download/ - You just download the standalone at the bottom of the page. Thats basiclly as simple as it gets. Windows dosen't have anything that can encrypt files on its own. You'll need to download something.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I will check it out now.